# Android SimpleCursorTreeAdapter Child Click

Tags: java, android

I have an expandable list using a simplecursortreeadapter

How would I integrate an onclicklistener or any way to change the

Below is my script so far. I was trying to use the onclicklistener at the bottom of this post, but I cannot figure out how to change it from a listview to expandable listview listener for the children.

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.cattest);

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            Cursor groupCursor = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM countries", null);
            MySimpleCursorTreeAdapter mscta = new MySimpleCursorTreeAdapter(
                                                    this,
                                                    groupCursor,
                                                    R.layout.employee_list_item,
                                                    new String[] {"country"},
                                                    new int[] {R.id.country},
                                                    R.layout.employee_list_item,
                                                    new String[] {"employee"},
                                                    new int[] {R.id.lastName});
            setListAdapter(mscta);
            checkDB.close();


    }

    class MySimpleCursorTreeAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter{

            public MySimpleCursorTreeAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor,
                            int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
                            int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
                    super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom,
                                    childTo);
            }


            @Override
            protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
                    String countryID = Integer.toString(groupCursor.getInt(0));
                    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
                    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

                    Cursor value = checkDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE _id='"+ countryID +"'", null);

                    String test = "";
                    if(value.moveToFirst())
                            test =  value.getInt(0) + ": " + value.getString(1);
                    while(value.moveToNext()){
                            test += ";" + value.getInt(0) + ": " + value.getString(1);
                    }
                    return value;
            }
    }
```

Tried implementing this

```
questionList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
sample(typedText);

questionList.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener()
        {                   
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(All.this, com.second.app.Second.class);
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
                intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                //Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
                //intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                startActivity(intent);
            }   
        }       
);
```

EDIT:

```
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
            int childPosition, long id) {
        // use groupPosition and childPosition to locate the current item in the adapter

            Intent intent = new Intent(Categories.this, com.second.app.Second.class);
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mscta.getItem(childPosition);
            intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            //Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
            //intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
            startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
```

At the moment the getChild(childPosition); is outputting the error

> The method getItem(int) is undefined for the type
>   Categories.MySimpleCursorTreeAdapter

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the setOnChildClickListener method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnChildClickListener(android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener)

Comment: thank you. That looks just right. Can you please provide any samples and examples?

Comment: it's not too complicated, but here is one: http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/CustomExpandableListView/src/com/beanie/example/list/SampleActivity.java

Comment: thank you. I have edited the above post. And am now getting an error

Comment: you probably need to override the method getItem in your adapter